# Subviews for elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, frameworks, single-page-application

I want to have an single-page App (AngularJS) with following views:

- Login
- Main View

Now the Main-View should have different "elements":
- Toolbar
- Main Content Div
- 2 Sidebars

Can I handle all this elements as a subview? I would like to have a .html Template for each of these "elements".

Thank you very much!

Comment: look at ng-include directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not split into two base html. That is not good design for Angularjs apps and it will be creating problem while running test cases (unit or end-2end test cases).

Please look the below code. Here "userLoggedIn" is a $rootscope variable for loading necessary block based on authentication.

```
<div ng-include="'views/common/loginHeader.html'" ng-show="!userLoggedIn"></div> <!-- loginHeader -->
<div ng-include="'views/common/userHeader.html'" ng-show="userLoggedIn"></div> <!-- userHeader -->  

<div class="container" ng-view></div> <!-- body -->>

<div ng-include="'views/common/footer.html'"></div> <!-- footer -->
```

After authentication, you can set boolean flag or object to that variable.

```
$rootScope.userLoggedIn= true
```

(or)

```
$rootScope.userLoggedIn= {"name":"john smith", "settings":[{}]}
```

In logout controller, you can set false for hiding authentication containers and redirect to login page.

```
$rootScope.userLoggedIn= false;
```